# How to hide all the elements except first <div> and its child?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML code structure like this

```
<div id="content">
  <div>   //start
    <div id="title"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    .....more.....
  </div>   //end  
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    .....more.....
  </div>  
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    .....more.....
  </div>
  .....more div like above....
</div>
```

I want to use a piece of JQuery code to hide everything except the "div" has id="title"(keep the code from //start to //end).

Now, my JQuery code is:

```
$("div:not(:has(#title))").hide();
```

It shows "div id="title"""div"", but it also hide the several "div" after "div id="title"""div"". Again, I want to keep the code from //start to //end. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Basically hide all immediate div child of content except the first child

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to hide the *siblings* of the div that contains the `#title` element, then:

```
$("#title").parent().siblings().hide();
```

- `$("#title")` - find the element with the `id` `"title"`
- `.parent()` - go up to its parent
- `.siblings()` - get the *siblings* of the parent
- `.hide()` - hide them